# how to measure Software as a services performace

Tags: cloud, software-design, saas, scientific-computing

i wnat to measure software as a  service(SAAS) performace that i works with this new project SAAS optimization
can you share knowledge about this

1. what are the way are available now
2. how to optimize web performance the software as a  service

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For real performance measurement of the application you can use APM(application performance monitoring) tools like Oracle RUEI.

If you want web analytics type of solution then you can try google analytics.